# Visual Studio 2005 Deployment

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

I have created an application on Windows XP, Visual Studio 2005, C++.
I want to run the application using its .EXE file on a **different computer** but it crashes.
I think it maybe related to some .dll missing files.

Am I in the right direction? 
If so, how do I know which files are missing?
Is there a build option in the Visual to copy all the requested .dll to a specific place?

Thanks,
Asaf

Comment: I seem to recall having major issues trying to deploy C++ software written in VS2005 onto any computer without VS installed. It was the main reason why I stopped using VS for C++ work. Unfortunately I don't know where the information was it's been a while, if I manage to track down some references I'll post an answer later.

Comment: What is the error message that you get when trying to run the application? A crash can or cannot be related to dlls, and the error message will probably hint in the right direction

Comment: Thank you Amos. David, the message is "access violation"... and on my pc I dont get this message

Answer (score 5):

The most likely answer is that the other computer is missing the Microsoft VC++ redistributable files. You can download the VS2005 (or VS2005 SP1) file from Microsoft. It's name is `vcredist_x86.exe` (assuming standard x86 build). Just run it on the target PC and then retry your app.

Comment: As an alternative to installing the redistributable on the target machine, you could consider linking your application against the static run time rather than the dynamic run time (the latter is the default).

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks, first I will try to download the file and see what happens. Can you explain me about the linking part a bit?

Comment: I have downloaded the file but it didnt help me... is there something else I can do?

Comment: Well, my first question is: Did you make sure you matched the file to the version of VS? If so, then the other Dependency Walker answers are the way to go.

Comment: Yes, they match. I will try the Dependency Walker. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you assume it is a missing DLL you can also use the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)
But I agree to Joel that most probably it will be the redist package that is missing or if you tried to use a debug version you might need the non redist package.

But you don't have to download them. They should be part of your VS installation. Somewhere in the VC/redist folder.

Comment: I am making a release version. I saw the library inside VC directory. It contains dll, but from which directory should I take them: ATL, CRT, MFC, MFCLOC, OPENMP ( can I assume that regular project is CRT? )

Comment: Like the names tell you. Use the one like your project. So a regular project as you call it is CRT.

Answer (score 0):

I use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to watch which dlls are missing for my program.

Comment: I have used a different tool that does the same and I have downloaded all the dll it requires but it still crashes...

Answer (score 0):

There's an in depth discussion of the options and steps required to get Visual Studio 2005 C++ Applications to run on machines which don't have Visual Studio installed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikolad/archive/2005/09/02/460368.aspx).

It includes detailed instruction for Visual C++ Express users too.

Comment: Thanks Amos, I will have a look at it too